# How can I restrict a data annotation's usage to a particular property's data type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes, data-annotations

I have a validation attribute that inherits from ValidationAttribute. However, the particular usage of this attribute applies to lists only (IEnumerable really). How can I specify the usage of this property to only be used with items that inherit from IEnumerabe? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a compile time check? If so that's not possible. The `AttributeTargets` enum (used with the `AttributeUsageAttribute`) is as far as it goes on determining where attributes can go, and it's pretty simple. At run time you can check to see if the type is of type `IEnumerable` and throw an exception if not.